# Modificar Código Python sin detener el programa

Tags: python, ubuntu, consola

Tengo un programa en consola que utiliza el lenguaje python Y la pregunta es medio rara. Mi programa envía mensajes por API de Telegram y funciona perfecto, pero me falto poner que envié a un segundo Telegram.

El problema es que si detengo el programa pierdo todo lo que el programa estuvo haciendo y empieza de cero. La realidad es que quisiera que cambiar el código (agregar la otra dirección) sin detener el programa ¿Es posible? Sé que con Java hay una solución pero no sé con Python...

Comment: Si tu problema no tiene ningún dato, ni detalle importante que no hayas dado, la respuesta es sencilla.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario... Mi pregunta no requiere detalles ya que es algo que serviría para casi cualquier codigo

Comment: "Tengo un programa en consola" ¿Qué programa? ¿Un framework externo o te refieres a el scrip que has creado? ¿Por qué pierdes lo que el programa estuvo haciendo? ¿La BB.DD se corrompe? ¿Cómo estás ejecutando el programa con Cron? ¿Lees los datos en Streaming con Kafka? ¿Qué es lo que el programa estuvo haciendo? ¿Modificaciones en ficheros? ¿Extracción de datos? Es imposible ayudarte de una forma específica si planteas una pregunta  tan general, por ello mi comentario indicándote que la respuesta es sencilla y te la he dado debajo! Consiste en modificar el fichero y guardar las modificaciones

Comment: disculpa no tengo mucha experiencia.. es un scrip simple creado por mi que trabaja con mensajes...solo va haciendo cálculos en base a un valor recibido y nunca hice una BBDD para pausarlo y volverlo a arrancar.. por eso si llegara a detener el programa debería cargarlo manualmente... tu respuesta es buena... pero si hago el cambio en el archivo, para que surja efecto no debería detener el código y volverlo a ejecutar?

Comment: Genial, si  tan solo es un script, por favor edita tu pregunta con el código de dicho script para que podamos ver que está sucediendo, que perderías, y como tienes hecho el script. Por favor te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y [¿Cómo realizar un ejemplo mínimo verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para aprender a hacer buenas preguntas en StackOverflow y que puedas ser ayudada con más facilidad!

Answer (score 0):

Sería tan fácil como:

1. Copiar el archivo de Python que quieres modificar.
2. Realizar las modificaciones oportunas en la copia.
3. Una vez verificado que la copia funciona perfectamente, reemplazar el original por la copia.

Comment: Pero en ese caso.. Debería debería detener el programa y volverlo a iniciar? Porque eso es justamente lo que no quiero... En java hay una manera de hacerlo con Nodemon.. Pero no se como hacerlo en python..